# Error en Insert duplica los datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Actualmente tengo este trigger:

```
Tabla A: pin_id, type, number
Tabla B: pin_id, type, number
Tabla Inventario: id, number, name
```

La tabla A solo almacena el histórico de entradas de registros sin validar sin son válidos o no, es por ello que si se inserta un registro en la tabla B, le digo a un dispositivo electrónico que active una salida.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `insertar_dato` AFTER INSERT ON `tabla A`
       FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

         INSERT INTO tabla B(pin_id, type, number) 

         SELECT pin_id, type, number from tabla A where EXISTS(select * 
       from inventario 
      where number = NEW.number);
 END
```

Intenté realizar esto:

```
IF EXISTS(select * from inventario 
          where number = NEW.number)
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO tabla B(pin_id, type, number) 
            SELECT pin_id, type, 1 number tabla A;
       END
```

En la Tabla A realicé un insert con estos campos(valores): *pin_id (100), type(9), number(12345)*, hice el procedimiento almanenado para que la Tabla B  realice un insert, con todos los campos de A si *number (12345)* existe en tabla *Inventario*.

El trigger realiza el insert pero si mi tabla contiene 8 registros que contienen el *number(12345)* (el number 12345 está registrado en inventario), vuelve a insertar los 8 registros: lo que deseo es que solo se inserte el registro actual, ya que el trigger funciona ok pero duplicando todo.

con las recomendaciones sugeridas realicé esto y funcionó perfectamente:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `insertar_dato` AFTER INSERT ON `tabla A`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    
     DECLARE `conteo_number` integer;
  
     SET @conteo_number = (select count(*) 
      from `inventario`
      where number := NEW.number);
  
     IF @conteo_number = 1 then

        INSERT INTO tabla B(pin_id, type, number) 
    
        VALUES (NEW.pin_id, NEW.type, NEW.Number);
     END IF;
   END
```

Comment: Y si, en vez de hacer un select que traiga toooodo, usas sólo el registro nuevo que estás insertando? NEW.campo1, NEW.campo2,... ni idea cómo sea tabla A pero sería algo así

Comment: @Alfabravo reviso lo que comentas el tema es que debe insertar en la tabla B solo si el codigo está registrado en el inventario

Comment: Entonces es IF (resultado_de_select_count = 1) insert into B New.A, New.B,... o comparando con > 0, tú dirás qué te sirve más. Sigue sin tener sentido insertar toooodo el select. Por favor, completa tu pregunta para poderte dar una respuesta. Descripción de las tablas y algún dato de prueba ;)

Comment: @Alfabravo edite mi pregunta para explicar mejor el tema, por otro lado tengo muy escasos conocimientos en bases de datos y eso fue he realizado hasta ahora que funciona pero con el problema que comento, voy analizar lo que dices

Comment: Leyendo la pregunta, no queda claro que es lo que quieres lograr. Quizás debas empezar o terminar la pregunta explicando claramente cuál es el comportamiento esperado, ya que sin saber ese _detalle_, resulta imposible ver qué está mal con el código.

Comment: @jachguate edite la pregunta para ver si se logra comprender mejor

Comment: Está raro porque el conteo retornaría un número y lo estás comparando con un varchar. Pero bueh, no sé cómo sea mysql en esos casos. Lo otro: dos veces? Seguro estás intentando insertar una sola vez en tablaA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo mysql a la mano, pero debería ser algo similar a

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `insertar_dato` AFTER INSERT ON `tabla_a`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE `conteo_inventario` integer;
  
  SET @conteo_inventario := (select count(*) 
      from `inventario`
      where codigo = NEW.codigo);
  
  IF (conteo_inventario > 0)
      INSERT INTO tabla B(pin_id, type, number) 
      VALUES(NEW.pin_id, NEW.type, NEW.number);
  );
  END IF
  
END;
$$
```

La idea es que revises cómo se valida si hay coincidencias en inventario, porque entre otras cosas, tu ejemplo mínimo no tiene datos de prueba y lo que está en tu trigger fallido tiene nombres de campo diferentes a los campos que pones arriba en la pregunta (`NEW.codigo` ?????).

PD. Me parece poco considerado que no le gastes tiempo a poner datos de prueba y una descripción de las tablas más clara; toca escribir código a ciegas y adivinar sin saber si volverás diciendo "no me funcionó".

Nota: Usé [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841455/declare-variable-mysql-trigger) para revisar detalles de la sintaxis de los trigger en MySQL.

Comment: realice el procedimiento almacenado que sugieres y realiza el insert actual pero lo inserta duplicado

Comment: @IngDePáez el trigger que sugiero hace UN insert de UN registro. Por lo tanto, el problema está en tu implementación. Por favor, edita nuevamente tu pregunta y **añade** COMPLETO lo que intentaste de acuerdo a la respuesta Y el resultado (no necesitas borrar lo anterior).

Comment: realice la modificacion con el trigger que sugeristes para que lo puedas observar

Comment: Gracias finalmente solucioné el tema, muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda @alfabravo

Comment: @IngDePáez con gusto! me alegra poder ayudar en algo